# Что нужно знать разрабатывая драйвер периферии? Эмуляция устройств для ПК

Tags: c, драйвер

Система Windows 7-10

Порт: USB или COM-port

Цель: Драйвер для устройства

Язык написания я так полагаю С?

Интересна любая информация по теме, книги, форумы, статьи, хороший подсказ :)

Насколько сложно и что для этого нужно, чтобы ПО для подключения VR оборудования приняло устройства с написанными драйверами за соответствующее?

(ПО- к примеру SteamVR)

Comment: Посмотрите вначале на DDK. Там есть примеры "пустого" драйвера (т.е такого, котрый подключается и ничего не делает) А вообще - многое зависит от софта, сейчас в моде Oculus Quest 2, там никаких портов, просто свой собственный sdk. А вот - вводная сатья: https://habr.com/ru/post/40466/

Comment: S.H. , Благодарю за ответ!!! Если честно не верил что кто то ответит так хорошо)) Потому что в инете куча тем с вопросом, похожим на мой, но без каких либо ответов) А по поводу VR , мне не нужны другие производители, я хочу чтобы VR игра просто работала от моих контроллеров, мною собранных, не от брендовых.

Comment: Успехов Вам. Именно те люди, которые делают что то своё, а не покупают разрекламированое рыночное решение, в конце концов делают шаг вперед.